# Updating a parent structure reference golang

Tags: go

I am new to Golang. I have this example here - https://go.dev/play/p/lusSZk5be4b

I am trying to update the global parent structure from one of the elements of the same parent structure. I was expecting this program might create an issue because of updating the parent structure from it's own child but this seems to work fine.

I did not understand if this is the right behaviour and is accepted in golang or this kind of updating the parent from child should not be done at all. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually replacing the parent, but the global variable.
If you keep a reference to the original parent you'll see things remain the same there:

https://go.dev/play/p/FsNVdheZPfE

```
func main() {
    p = &parent{}
    oldParent = p
    ...
    fmt.Pritnln(oldParent)
    ...
```

Even if you had an actual parent on the child struct and update it (example: https://go.dev/play/p/hELKFB7DWc- ) , the original reference would still have the child, but the child would have a parent with no children.

So in summary, you're just updating references which is totally valid. Whether that makes sense in code or you might lose an important reference that's a different thing.

Comment: I used the word  "references" but they're actually pointers.

Comment: In the first example, how long does the go compiler keeps the `oldParent` around? Because the global variable has already been replaced.

In the second example, I tried printing here - https://go.dev/play/p/JyOCqDsAwS3. `but the child would have a parent with no children.`, I am seeing the same parent in the child after update.

Comment: Ah.. that's kind of silly, it's because the child method is a copy of childStruct and not a  pointer, so when invoked, the value is copied, creates a new parent and disappears, if you update it to be a pointer it will work as described: https://go.dev/play/p/_wgSzCG65gi

Comment: I cleaned up and created a new example for this last topic. Try replacing line 18 https://go.dev/play/p/atI6aJnO6Vl

Comment: okay thank you for the examples. I would want to know about this -  In the first example, how long does the go compiler keeps the oldParent around? Because the global variable has already been replaced.

Comment: I would think it would get collected on the next garbage collector cycle, but for this tiny program it will most likely would be as long as the program lives. 
Here's more information about Go's GC https://go.dev/doc/gc-guide